# Typescript discriminated union with intersection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

[Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-johnson-0yctfg?file=/src/types.ts)

I have a type

```js
type TFormFieldFileProps = {
    componentProps: TFileUploaderProps;
    select?: never;
    checkbox?: never;
    file: true;
};

type TFormFieldSelectProps = {
    componentProps: TCustomSelectProps;
    select: true;
    checkbox?: never;
    file?: never;
};

type TFormFieldCheckboxProps = {
    componentProps: TCustomCheckboxProps;
    select?: never;
    checkbox: true;
    file?: never;
};

type TFormFieldInputProps = {
    componentProps: TCustomInputProps;
    select?: never;
    checkbox?: never;
    file?: never;
};

export type TFormFieldProps = { boxProps?: BoxProps } & (
    | TFormFieldCheckboxProps
    | TFormFieldInputProps
    | TFormFieldSelectProps
    | TFormFieldFileProps
);
```

I want to remove `componentProps` prop and instead set each type to be an intersection of `componentProps` prop type and the other `select checkbox file` type.

```js
type TFormFieldFileProps = TFileUploaderProps & {
    select?: never;
    checkbox?: never;
    file: true;
};

type TFormFieldSelectProps = TCustomSelectProps & {
    select: true;
    checkbox?: never;
    file?: never;
};

type TFormFieldCheckboxProps = TCustomCheckboxProps & {
    select?: never;
    checkbox: true;
    file?: never;
};

type TFormFieldInputProps = TCustomInputProps & {
    select?: never;
    checkbox?: never;
    file?: never;
};

export type TFormFieldProps = { boxProps?: BoxProps } & (
    | TFormFieldCheckboxProps
    | TFormFieldInputProps
    | TFormFieldSelectProps
    | TFormFieldFileProps
);
```

But it doesn't work.

```js
const FormField = (props: TFormFieldProps) => {
    const { select, checkbox, file, boxProps, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <Box
            {...boxProps}
            sx={{ '& > *': { width: 1 } }}
        >
            {select ? (
                // error: missing some property from TFormFieldCheckboxProps
                <CustomSelect {...rest} />
            ) : checkbox ? (
                // error: missing some property from TFormFieldInputProps
                <CustomCheckbox {...rest} />
            ) : file ? (
                // error: missing some property from ...
                <FileUploader {...rest} />
            ) : (
                // error: missing some property from ...
                <CustomInput {...rest} />
            )}
        </Box>
    );
};
```

I understand why it doesn't work but I don't understand how to solve this problem without having to specify each property on each type...

Can I make it work without writing all the props from all the types in all discriminated union types? If so, how?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  Right now I just get all kinds of errors on undeclared types.  Maybe you could also pare it down to some example with fewer union members that still shows the issue?

Comment: @jcalz https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-johnson-0yctfg?file=/src/types.ts

Comment: I can't tell if the errors I'm seeing are the same ones you're talking about.  I see "xxx has no props in common" and not "missing properties".  I'd really rather see a stripped-down, minimal example, in plain text, in the question itself... which could be pasted into a single file in a standalone IDE.   The full context of the question should be present in the question text.

Comment: I *think* this is currently not possible, and there is a recent open suggestion at [ms/TS#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680).  If that addresses your question, I can write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that's exactly the problem I'm having here. Would appreciate your answer

Comment: its problem with your code itself, like you could have done much simpler way buy keeping 2 variables. one for choosing input type (`props.type`), one for children props (`props.attrs` )  and use generics to type check the `props.attrs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently when you shatter a type, the extracted variables are no longer associated with each other when parsed by the compiler. Using `if`/`switch`/etc will no longer change the types of the other variables.

```
const { select, checkbox, file, ...rest } = props;

/*
select is true | undefined
checkbox is true | undefined
file is true | undefined
rest is { checked: boolean; } | { variant: "filled" | "outlined"; } | { options: string[]; } | { ext: string[]; maxSize: number; }
*/
```

With the way your types are defined, you would have to use the following logic to type guard in a way the compiler understands:

```
const FormField = (props: TFormFieldProps) => {
  let inputElement;
  if (props.select) {
    const { select, checkbox, file, options, ...rest } = props;
    inputElement = (
      <select { ...rest }>
        { options.map(o => (<option value={o}>{o}</option>)) }
      </select>
    );
  } else if (props.checkbox) {
    const { select, checkbox, file, ...rest } = props;
    inputElement = (<input type="checkbox" {...rest} />);
  } else if (props.file) {
    const { select, checkbox, file, ...rest } = props;
    inputElement = (<input type="file" {...rest} />);
  } else {
    const { select, checkbox, file, variant, ...rest } = props;
    // TODO: do something with variant as its not a valid <input> prop
    inputElement = (<input {...rest} />);
  }
  
  return inputElement;
}
```

Although, I would instead use a single `type: "select" | "checkbox" | "file" | "custom"` property instead of `select`, `file` and `checkbox`.

```
// FormField.ts
const FormField = (props: TFormFieldProps) => {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "select": { // <-- this brace is a container for the below const statement, not part of the switch statement
      const { type, options, ...rest } = props;
      return (
        <select { ...rest }>
          { options.map(val => (<option value={val}>{val}</option>)) }
        </select>
      );
    }
    case "checkbox":
      return (<input {...props} />);
    case "file": { // <-- same with this one
      const { ext, ...rest } = props;
      return (<input accept={ext.join(",")} {...props} />);
    }
    default: { // <-- and this one
      const { type, variant, ...rest } = props;
      // TODO: do something with variant as its not a valid <input> prop
      return (<input {...rest} />);
    }
  }
}
```

```
// types.ts
type TFileUploaderProps = {
  ext: string[];
  maxSize: number;
  type: "file"
};

type TCustomSelectProps = {
  options: string[];
  type: "select"
};

type TCustomCheckboxProps = {
  checked: boolean;
  type: "checkbox"
};

type TCustomInputProps = {
  variant: "filled" | "outlined";
  type: "custom"
};

export type TFormFieldProps =
  | TCustomCheckboxProps
  | TCustomInputProps
  | TCustomSelectProps
  | TFileUploaderProps;
```

```js
// Usage:
(<FormField type="checkbox" checked />)
(<FormField type="custom" />)
(<FormField type="file" ext={["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]} maxSize=1024 />)
(<FormField type="select" options={["a", "b", "c"]} />)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. 

That's so weird though. When I destructure `type` from `props` and `switch (type)` it doesn't work. But when I `switch (props.type)` it does .

Comment: @pythondeveloper999 It's just something that parser doesn't understand yet because of the complexity that comes from walking back up the code to figure the types out. As jcalz covers in their answer, there's a feature request to add support for it but it might be a while off.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, the issue here is that, while TypeScript 4.6 and above supports [control flow analysis on destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), this does not work for [rest properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) (as of TypeScript 4.7).

So, this works:

```
interface Foo { type: "foo"; rest: { x: string } }
interface Bar { type: "bar"; rest: { y: number } }

const process = ({ type, rest }: Foo | Bar) =>
  type === "foo" ? rest.x : rest.y; // okay
```

but this fails:

```
interface Foo { type: "foo"; x: string }
interface Bar { type: "bar"; y: number }

const process = ({ type, ...rest }: Foo | Bar) =>
  type === "foo" ? rest.x : rest.y; // errors
// -------------------> ~ -----> ~
// Property does not exist on {x: string} | {y: number}
```

There's a recent open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680) to support this, but it hasn't been implemented yet.  You might want to give that issue a  and/or mention your use case (and why it's compelling), but I don't know if it will have any effect.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1A9gJwNZSQbwCgkkBLYAFwgwDMFkAxNNfJcgTxggC4kAiaprwDcSDNHI88SAB48o5DGQDmSAL5qipClVqIkAIRAYW7Tj14AjI8NHjJSNj2ABXMBapqNm+GmDykMBhoiFC4ALxIABRSphAANLb+qjyMzAA+BkYAlEhhAHyaxLG5YRH8gkgA-InkAHTSSDxi8rVsIgD07UhoWCBsBASqAwSgkLB0SPQgJAA2uITEZJQ0E6kmHNx8Amg2skjyisAqQ4vaK3qGxjEb5lYYNo5ILm4eQ96+-oHB0OFR15wJWpA5rkNQpJhIDKXHL5QqsDYlMrbXhVGr1RpotpITpIKhBDBQTQ4gC0pLJ5Ip5LySAAfkgKdSaUSugAFIKcDDsJAAEzQ0CeaFBEGkJH8vnwewOynUGTwj2e7gwQzeQA)